# Java cant convert From Student to Student[]

Tags: java, arrays, class

Hey guys Can i get some help with this java project my problem is this line Student s = new Student(r.getChar(),r.getChar(),r.getNum(),r.getNum()); i want to make it an array but if i try to replace Student s whit Student s[i]= new Student(r.getChar()........) i get an error telling me i cant convert from Student to Student[] i nead a solution to make it an array

Dont mind r.getChar()

```
public class Student extends Person {
  private int grade;
  public Student(String name, String address, int age, int grade) {
    super(name, address, age);
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  public void setGrade(int grade){
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  public int getGrade(){
    return grade;
  }
}

public class Person{
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private int age ;

  public Person(String name,String address,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address = address;
  }

  public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public String getAddress(){
    return address;
  }

  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to trim down your code to that minimum that is required to make your point. Proper formatting might also help a little.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you would create an array of `Student`s:

```
Students allStudents[] = new Students[x];
```

Which would create an array of `x` elements, all initialized to `null`. Then you would initialize each of those elements within a loop or something:

```
allStudents[i] = new Student(...);
```

Comment: Dammm i have been trying to figure this out for the last 2 hours thanks a lod :D it worked

Comment: Spoke too soon i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Colin Snow: The exception says it all, your array index is bigger than the array length. Note that an array of size `n` is indexed from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: ok i corected the problem and i did a System.out.println(allStudents) but i get Student@c17164 code: Student allStudents[] = new Student[x];
 
 for(int i=0;i<x;i++) 
 {
 allStudents[i] = new Student(r.getChar(),r.getChar(),r.getNum(),r.getNum());
 }
 System.out.println(allStudents[1]);
 } 
}

Comment: Can i insert that much information Name Addres Age and Grade in allStundets[0] ? i mean it lets me insert all of it but the output is wrong ... and random

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an array with just 1 element?
In that case, you need to first allocate the array and then assign an reference to element number 0.

Something like
Student[] s=new Student[1]; // Allocate array
s[0]=new Student(...) // Normal constructer call

Comment: hey no i want to make an array with x elements

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the first answer way you could use the short notation:

```
Student students[] = {new Student(..)};
```

This is the same thing but a bit shorter.